# About the volume of the graphics of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ revolved around the $x$-axis.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have to determine whether the following improper integral is convergent or divergent: the volume obtained when the area between the $x$-axis for $x\ge 1$ and the graph of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is revolved about the $x$-axis.
[image]

What should I do in this question?
Evaluate limit for integral $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ from $1$ to $+\infty$ or what?

Comment: Is it really $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ that gives the volume? What you first should do is to try to find the correct integral. Also, the exercise tell you not to evaluate the integral. So, how can one prove convergence/divergence of an integral without calculating it?

Answer (score 1):

By Cavalieri's principle, we just have to understand if the integral:
$$ V=\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx \tag{1}$$
is convergent or not. Obviously it is, since $0\leq\sin^2 x\leq x^2$ gives:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}1\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2} = 2.\tag{2}$$
Using integration by parts, it is not difficult to compute $V$:

$$ \color{red}{V}=\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx = \pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\,dx = \pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: In the question, only $x\geq 1$ is considered.

Comment: @mickep: I noticed it later. It is not a real issue, I just proved a stronger result. The volume in the case $x\geq 1$ is slightly uglier but just as difficult to compute: $$ V_{x\geq 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}\,\left(\pi+1-\cos(2)-2\,\text{Si}(2)\right).$$

Comment: Even though it is nice to know that the integral can be calculated exactly, it is explicitly written that one should not. So, my point was (even though i did not write that) that the answer can be shortened to say that $0\leq\pi\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\leq \pi\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=1$ and refer to monotonicity of the integral, but of course _you_ know that (but does OP?)...

Answer (score 0):

The resulting solid is composed by infinitely many "pieces" which meet in single points (as the figure shows clearly). You can put the $k$-th piece in a cylinder which has radius which is $C/k$ and height which is $\pi$. So the $k$-th cylinder has volume $C'/k^2$... and the sum is then finite.